# How to solve the diophantine equation $x^2-x=y^3$

Tags: diophantine-equations

> How would I solve the diophantine equation $x^2-x=y^3$?

Would anyone be able to help solve this equation?

We have only done equations up to powers of $2$ as of now.

Comment: Rewrite it as $y^3 = x(x-1),$ and note that $x$ and $x-1$ are coprime.

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy  When you want to edit a post, please don't put words in the mouth of the asker.

Comment: @saulspatz Where would you go from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y^3=x^2-x=x(x-1)$ In the prime factorization of $y^3,$ the exponent of every prime is a multiple of $3.$  Since $x, x-1$ are coprime, none of these primes occurs in both the factorization of $x$ and of $x-1$ so both $x$ and $x-1$ are cubes.

I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Aaaaand since there are no consecutive cubes(...... well besides $-1$,$0$ and $1$.... )that don't involve $0$, the only solution is $(0,0)$!  Awesome